# Java: Scanner stopping at new line

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to scan through text files and add them to a map, the map and everything is working. **However, the scanner seems to be stopping when it comes to a 'enter' in the text file, or a blank line. This is my problem**

here is my block of code for the scanner/mapper

```
class OneButtonListener implements ActionListener
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
    {
        final JFileChooser oneFC = new JFileChooser();
        oneFC.showOpenDialog(AnalysisFrame.this);
        String newLine = null;
        oneFC.getName(null);
        int returnVal = 0;
        File fileOne = oneFC.getSelectedFile();

        Scanner input = null;        
        try {
            input = new Scanner(fileOne);
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AnalysisFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null,
                            ex);
        }                       
        inputText = input.nextLine(); 
        String[] words = inputText.split("[ \n\t\r,.;:!?(){}]");

        for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
            key = words[i].toLowerCase(); 

            if (words[i].length() > 1){
                if (mapOne.get(key) == null){
                    mapOne.put(key, 1);
                }
                else {
                    value1 = mapOne.get(key).intValue();
                    value1++;
                    apOne.put(key, value1);
                }
            } 
         }
     }
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: No error, just not expected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You should scan inside a loop until it reaches the end of the file, for example:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
while(input.hasNextLine()){
    builder.append(input.nextLine());
    builder.append(" "); // might not be necessary
}
String inputText = builder.toString();
```

An alternative to using `split` could be to use a [Delimiter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter%28java.util.regex.Pattern%29) with the `Scanner` and use `hasNext()` and `next()` instead of `hasNextLine()` and `nextLine()`. Try it out, see if it works.

For example:

```
scanner.useDelimiter("[ \n\t\r,.;:!?(){}]");
ArrayList<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>();
while(scanner.hasNext()){
    tokens.add(scanner.next());
}

String[] words = tokens.toArray(new String[0]); // optional
```

Also on a side note, it's not necessary to create the `JFileChooser` everytime:

```
class OneButtonListener implements ActionListener
{
    private final JFileChooser oneFC = new JFileChooser();

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
    {
```

Comment: Thanks for the example, however I am unsure how to implement it, what is "append" doing? I have used append to output into a textarea but here I am keeping it to place it into a map.

Comment: Notice that I'm using a `StringBuilder`. This allows for String concatenation that is more efficient than using `+=` to append Strings. To get the String from the `StringBuilder`, just call `toString()` on the `StringBuilder`. Read through the example again maybe?

Comment: O sorry that was before your edit, the 'append' is still erroring though

Also thank you for all the help

Comment: I no longer get an error anymore however it does not seem to be going past the first line still. 
`String inputText = builder.toString();` this line inserts the data from the builder in the inputText string correct? Making sure its not the builder I need to call later on

Comment: Consider using the second example that uses `ArrayList` instead of `StringBuilder` and `split`. Do something like `word = input.next(); System.out.println(word); tokens.add(word);` to see what's happening. I've added that to the example, remember to take it out again later.

Comment: Also remember to `close()` the Scanner when you're done using it.

Comment: Hmm unfortunatly I am having a hard time figuring out how to include that properly.

I think it may be because the next part of my code requires a String[] while the only way I can get your code in error free I have to set "word" as a String while it wants a String[].

Comment: Did you notice `String[] words = tokens.toArray(new String[0]);`?

Comment: got it all in there now and it still says it found: String required: String[]

Comment: Copy and paste the example, because you should only call `toArray` after you've added all the words. :p

Comment: Also notice how the array is called `words`.

Comment: `word` was only introduced to debug the Scanner. See the commented line? If everything works, that should be the only line in the while loop. PS: Here's a nice color scheme for Netbeans, just import it. :) http://rt.hnnnglmbrg.de/netbeans.zip

Comment: Thanks for all the help it is fully working now! Can't thank you enough. Also thanks for the color scheme!

Answer (score 0):

Not having worked with Java in a very long time I may be way off, but it looks like you call                 `inputText = input.nextLine();` exactly once, so it makes sense that you're only getting one line. Presumably you want to call `nextLine()` in a loop so that it keeps giving you lines until it gets to the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
String contentsOfWholeFile = new Scanner(file).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
```

Answer (score 0):

In `split("[ \n\t\r,.;:!?(){}]")`
add **`\f`**