# identifying a new line in a scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java: Scanner stopping at new line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10891511/java-scanner-stopping-at-new-line)

I'm new to programming and I was wondering if there is a way to identify when there is a new line in a `Scanner`. My method is supposed to take a `Scanner` of a text file and break the line if it is over 60 characters long without breaking it in the middle of a word.

The problem I'm having is since I'm going by each token my code doesn't account for lines that are less than 60 characters and appends them onto the previous line up to 60 characters.

This is the method I have created:

```
public static void wordWrap3(Scanner s) {
    String k = "";
    int length = 0;
    while(s.hasNext()) {
        k = s.next();
        length = length + k.length() + 1;
        if (length>60) {
            System.out.print("\n");
            length = 0;
        }
        System.out.print(" " + k);
    }
}
```

This is the text I am using:

```
We're no strangers to love, You know the rules and so do I, 
A full commitment's what Im thinking of, You wouldn't get this from any other guy.
I just wanna tell you how I'm feeling, Gotta make you understand.
Never gonna give you up, Never gonna let you down, Never gonna run around and desert you.
Never gonna make you cry, Never gonna say goodbye, Never gonna tell a lie and hurt you.
```

Comment: It's not clear to me - are you trying to put *existing* lines together as well, or just *insert* line breaks? If it's the latter, simply read one line at a time with `nextLine()`...

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10891511/java-scanner-stopping-at-new-line?rq=1

Comment: so you want to put a newline char after 60 chars?

Comment: Hmmm ... are you trying to rickroll SO?  :-)

Comment: im trying to insert existing line breaks. the problem i run into when reading one line at a time is that it still breaks in the middle of a word. thats why i was reading by token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be saying that you want to word wrap each line separately.  If so, the simple solution is to split the input into lines, and then create a scanner for each line and pass that to your existing `wordWrap3` method.

Comment: are you saying that i should create another scanner and then pass that scanner one line at a time from the previous scanner? im using a website called practice it so all i have control over is the method, not the actual program.

Comment: Yes.  I am saying that.  If you are constrained so that your code has to go into that method, then you will need to organize it differently, but the basic logic should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
 String fileLine = "";
 while(s.hasNextLine()) {
     fileLine = s.nextLine();
     if(fileLine.length() > 60 )
     {
         while (fileLine.length() > 60)
         {
             String tempStr = fileLine.substring(0, 60);
             int rightIdx = tempStr.lastIndexOf(' ');
             String firstStr = tempStr.substring(0, rightIdx);
             String secStr = fileLine.substring(rightIdx + 1, fileLine.length());
             System.out.println(firstStr);
             //if still it is big
             if(secStr.length() > 60)
                 fileLine = secStr;
             else
             {
                 System.out.println(secStr);
                 break;
             }
         }
     }
     else
     {
         System.out.println(fileLine);
     }
 }
```

ofcourse it can be improved further.

Comment: how would i implement this for a line with 120 characters? would i just put the if statement in a loop?

Comment: updated code for that, and it can be improved further, I just provided some help, not fully working, efficient code